# How do you update a file if already existing in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

As if now, I am checking if file is already available in S3 bucket or not, if file is there then I am getting the content of file and appending the content to it and again uploading the file to S3. This new file is now having older plus new data.

If file is not there then I am creating a new file.

Do we have any better approach to update the file in S3? Please note, the complete process has to happen using Lambda.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no better approach since it's not possible to append to an S3 object.

Comment: Even I was suspect the same, thanks for confirming.